# Changing select programmatically after enabling it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, internet-explorer-6

I'm having some problems with the select element.
I want to be able to change the option selected programmatically, with support for IE6 (that's the bad guy!).
So what I do is set the selectedIndex with the value it should be, now comes the caveat, this doesn't work when the control is disabled, so I enable it and than try to change the selectedIndex by this order. The control gets enabled but doesn't change selection.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

I've tried changing the index with the following codes:

```
this._select.attr('selectedIndex',index);
```

and

```
this._select.get(0).selectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so we can see what you've tried already.

Comment: Please post your code, your question is pretty useless without it.  You could also try and set up a small example on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.

Comment: The code is too complex to post it here, i've tried to isolate this problem without success, so the problem is not from enabling the select element. But if I put a delay between the enable and the index change it works, so that's just weird.

Comment: I have created a fiddle with my better understanding and posting here..  http://jsfiddle.net/u5uhD/ .If someone else understand it some more better update this fiddle and post here please

Comment: Post the HTML that goes along with this, as well as more of the Javascript code - knowing when, and in which context, you're calling that code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me, even the select was disabled. Why don't you use `this._select.val('3');` to change it? In any case `this._select.val('3')` worked as well as `this._select.get(0).selectedIndex = index;`

Check your error console in your browser, you may have an error that is stopping the whole script from working.

Comment: Because I needed IE6 support.